# Where is the relocation information in the ELF format?

Tags: linux, linker, elf

Quoting "Linkers and Loaders" in the Loaders part

> "load-time relocation is far simpler than link-time relocation, 
>   because the entire program is relocated as a unit. [...] 
>   After reading the program into memory, the loader consults
>   the relocation items in the object file and fixes up the memory
>   locations to which the items point"

Maybe I misunderstood this point and this is only in some architectures, but my question is: where in the ELF format is specified which items need relocation at load time? how can I inquire for this list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relocations are to be found in special relocation sections in the ELF file. You can use the `readelf --sections` command to find out what sections are there in an executable or a shared library and those of type `REL` contain relocation instructions. The content of those relocation sections can be displayed using `readelf --relocs`. For example:

```
$ readelf --relocs /bin/ls

Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x16c8 contains 5 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
00000061afd8  000c00000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
00000061b540  006d00000005 R_X86_64_COPY     000000000061b540 optind + 0
00000061b548  006e00000005 R_X86_64_COPY     000000000061b548 optarg + 0
00000061b550  006a00000005 R_X86_64_COPY     000000000061b550 stderr + 0
00000061b560  006600000005 R_X86_64_COPY     000000000061b560 stdout + 0

Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x1740 contains 99 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
00000061b000  000100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 strcoll + 0
00000061b008  000200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 mktime + 0
...
```

The `.rela.dyn` section contains references to references in the program's code of code or data symbols that have to be relocated at load time while `.rela.plt` contains mostly jump slots that are used to call functions in shared objects. Note that usually only shared objects are compiled as position-independent code while the usual executables are not. This is due to the fact that PIC code is a bit slower than non-PIC code.